# Labels/texts are not displayed initially on page load in an angular2 app

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-material

I have an angular2 app. In my page, text or any labels do not load initially. When I select any style and uncheck that, the texts start displaying. Any idea, why is this weird thing happening? I am not sure if we can handle this through CSS or something wrong with the inclusion of files in my angular2 app. Any inputs is appreciable.

In my template file-

```
<div class="row">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>{{name}}</td>
</tr>
</table
</div>
```

In my .ts file-

```
ngOnInit(){
this.getStudentInfo();
}
getStudentInfo(){
this.globalObject.getFullData().subscribe(
(data)=>{

this.name= data.student.name;
});
}
```

In globalObject.ts-

```
setFullData(data){
this.completeData=data;
}
getFullData(data){
return Observable.of(this.completeData);
}
```

Another template file where I am using angular material design to display the content-

```
 <div class="wrapper">
     <md-card>
        <md-title>
        <h1>Student Information</h1>
        </md-title>
        <md-content>
        <div>
            <md-input aria-placeholder="Name" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)] = "" #name="ngModel"></md-input>
            <span class="validation">Name is required</span>
            </div>
        </md-content>
        </md-card>
    </div>
```

So, in my entire app, I save the data to global object when I have to navigate from one screen to another screen and I need to use the data. In the next screen, I get the data from the global object.This is the basic flow for my app.

In both the cases, the content does not display if I land to the screens.When I inspect and check and uncheck the particular styles, it starts displaying and retaing even after page refresh. Not sure, what's happening. Has anyone faced any similar kind of issues.

Comment: Probably change detection is not invoked for some reason. Please provide some code.

Comment: Its happening in my entire app. Not sure what's the reason.

Comment: Then please try to create a **minimal example** that allows to reproduce and post the code. Without that it's pretty much impossible to tell what's going on on your site. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you tell me if I need to invoke Change Detection ?

Comment: `[(ngModel)] = ""` doesn't look good. Why did you add that? What is `#name="ngModel"` supposed to do? What does "When I select any style and uncheck that" mean?

Comment: I am using #name="ngModel" to display the value as a placeholder to the text field.For the same text field , I have the static text which is hidden right now and should not be hidden. When I right click to the element lets say h1 which is right now hidden and deselect and reselect the properties, resolves the text hiding issue i.e text starts displaying in the page which is weird.

Comment: Sounds weird. Why don't you bind both to a field in the component?

Comment: "deselect, reselect" - what are you selecting, where? What's up with that `setFullData`? When is that set, where? :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer There are some legacy code as well. I will try to refactor my code.Thanks!

Comment: Hi GünterZöchbauer  - I have the same problem on almost all the pages, first time when the page loads - many a times no text is shown and pressing F5 on that page solves the issue always - what could be the reason